# HyperJAXB and ID/IDREF

Tags: jpa, jaxb, wsdl, hyperjaxb, idref

Has there been any update on using IDs and IDREFs for JAXB 2.x in HyperJAXB3?
[HyperJAXB and IDREFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993651/hyperjaxb-and-idrefs)

I've added a baseType binding to my IDREF element and the correct type is generated on the owner object, but the resulting class does not compile, as the unmarshal operation returns an Object.

```
    public void setCustomerObject(String target) {
        if (target!= null) {
            setCustomer(JAXBContextUtils.unmarshal(CustomerObjectContextPath, target));
        }
    }
```

The reason I want to use IDREFs is to avoid circular references in my WSDL, so if there is another solution or a less manual one, please let me know.